# Is there any method to call a function on clicking a date in mat-datepicker other than dateChange in angular 9?

Tags: angular, angular9, mat-datepicker

I need to call a function upon clicking a date in `mat-datepicker`. `dateChange` only calls a function if the selected date is changed. I need that function to be called if i click on the same date which is previously set. Is there any method to handle this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can always use the "closed" event of the [mat-date-picker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/api#MatDatepicker)

```
  <input #input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker">
  <mat-hint>MM/DD/YYYY</mat-hint>
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matIconSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle> 
  <mat-datepicker #picker (closed)="emit(input)"></mat-datepicker>
```